# Android lifecycle and external threads

Tags: android, android-activity

I've been staring at my app's log file for a couple of hours and just want to make sure what I see is even possible.

I have an Activity called ActivityA.

It starts up ThreadB.

ThreadB communicates with a server and sends the results back to ActivityA.

I am logging messages in ThreadB when it receives results from the server and sends them back to ActivityA

I am logging messages at the start and end of ActivityA's onDestroy() method.

Here's the weirdness.

ActivityA's onDestroy() method completes.  I know it completes because I see the message I print at the end of it in the log.

Then, ThreadB gets some very late input from the server.  ThreadB delivers it to ActivityA.

The routine in ActivityA that ThreadB communicates executes.  I know it executes because the messages it displays as it runs show in the log file AFTER ActivityA.onDestroy() has completed.

I thought once onDestroy() completed ActivityA would be unreachable.  IOW ThreadB could send messages to ActivityA as much as it wanted but ActivityA would not receive these messages because it didn't exist any more.

What in the world am I missing?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but If you declare the Thread in the same class, it still has access to the activities. Make sure, you stop the Thread in `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the [Object lifecycle](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Object_Lifecycle) and [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).
If you hold a reference to an Object (the activity in this case) you can execute methods on it.

The Activity lifecycle controls things on a higher abstraction level, determining if it's executing, being presented to the user, etc. It does not control whether methods can be invoked on the Activity object.

You can see this with a simple example:

```
public class DummyActivity extends Activity {
    public int nothing() {
        return 1;
    }
}

DummyActivity act = new DummyActivity();
act.nothing();
```

Here I create an Activity and call a method. It does not matter what's the state of the activity, it's only relevant if the object was created and I hold a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the ThreadB is a non static inner class of ActivityA, so it has reference to ActivityA, that is why ActivityA is not getting garbage collected. Even if its onDestroy() method is called.

JVM keeps the reference to the currently running thread, and ThreadB in turn has reference to ActivityA. So method of ActivityA gets executed even after onDestroy().

Make the tread as static inner class in your Activity and do not forget to stop your thread in onDestoy(). This would stop the method of ActivityA get executed after onDestroy().

Answer (score 0):

Callback onDestroy does not destroy *object* Activity, it's still *safe to make calls* to methods inside some Activity, Fragment or whatever after onDestroy called *if you do not touch view elements*.

By the way expected behaviour can be reached via Intents and BroadcastListener.
Just implement BroadcastListener with action "my.log.intent" in your activity, register it onStart() and unregister onStop().
Then send broadcast from your logger:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.log.intent");
intent.setExtras(someUsefulData);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and there you go:
your someUsefulData will be available to Activity regarding activity lifecycle. I.e. when activity visible to user and you are able manipulate contained views.